# Remove <span> from HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I delete a `<span>` tag from HTML page if it contains only comma?

Let's say I have 3 `<span>`, all what i want is to remove the `<span>` who has ONLY " , " as a content .

```
<span class"info">, </span>

<span class"info">information</span>

<span class"info">information</span>
```

Result: Delete this tag `<span class"info">, </span>`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to get `<SPAN>` based on test condition then `remove()` it.

```js
$('.info').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim() === ',';
}).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="info">, </span>
<span class="info">information</span>
<span class="info">information</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `regex`. What you can do is you can simply have a check on `$(this).text().trim() === ','` to know that the `span` contains only comma as a content.

```js
$('.info').each(function(){
  if($(this).text().trim() === ','){
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="info">, </span>
<span class="info">information</span>
<span class="info">information</span>
```

Comment: @Pete It will also remove `<span class="info">a, b</span>`

Comment: @Satpal is correct